# While using Kotlin, I'm having trouble using mutableSetOf() function. The function doesn't exist. The IDE gives a "Create function" option

Tags: kotlin

```
//Get volgate: Returns new voltage 

fun getVoltage() : MutableSet<T> {
  //Error exists: mutableSetOf() function.
  val mFinalValue : MutableSet<T> = mutableSetOf()
  .....
  ....
}
```

Comment: it's an inline function, what's your kotlin version. I don't think it is related to the kotlin version.

Comment: Do you not get an error on `T`?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this:

```
    class X<T> {
        fun some(): MutableSet<T> {
            val x: MutableSet<T> = mutableSetOf()
            return x
        }
    }
```

And I have no warning. So my suggestion to you is to invalidate/restart your Android Studio Cache, and sync gradle/rebuild your project.

With the information you provided, there's nothing inherently wrong at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify generic parameter T in the function signature

```
fun <T> getVoltage() : MutableSet<T>
```

instead of

```
fun getVoltage() : MutableSet<T>
```